# Polymer paper-toolbar not working properly

Tags: html, polymer

I have the following html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
</head>
<body>
    <paper-toolbar>
        <div class="title">Hello</div>
    </paper-toolbar>
</body>
</html>
```

And the page has a white gap between toolbar and the margin.

[image: Output]

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is caused by an inherent `margin: 8px` on the `<body>` tag. To fix this, you simply need to specify a margin yourself in CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Totally forgot about this haha. Thanks!